# Strong Induction and Recursion

Tags: combinatorics, induction, recursion

Consider the recursion given by \begin{equation}f(n) = 2f(n−1)− f(n−2)+6 \text{ for } n ≥ 2 \text{ with } f (0) = 2 \text{ and }f (1) = 4 \end{equation} 
Use mathematical induction to prove that \begin{equation}f (n) = 3n^2 −n+2 \text{ for all integers } n ≥ 0 \end{equation}

I don't see how I can use induction to prove this problem.

Comment: You could see [Arturo Magidin's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) on induction. You don't need strong induction for this.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $f(n)=3n^2-n+2$ holds true for $0\le n\le m-1$

So, using [Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction)/[Strong](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517440/whats-the-difference-between-simple-induction-and-strong-induction) induction

$f(m)=2f(m-1)-f(m-2)+6=\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

To find the result **without induction**:

$$f(n) = 2f(n−1)− f(n−2)+6\iff f(n)-f(n-1)=f(n-1)-f(n-2)+6$$
so
$$\sum_{k=2}^nf(k)-f(k-1)=f(n)-f(1)=\sum_{k=2}^n f(k-1)-f(k-2)+6\\=f(n-1)-f(0)+6(n-1)$$
so
$$f(n)-f(n-1)=2+6(n-1)$$
hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)-f(k-1)=f(n)-f(0)=\sum_{k=1}^n2+6(k-1)=2n+3(n-1)n$$
and finaly we have
$$f(n)=3n^2-n+2$$

Answer (score 0):

The base cases $n=0,1$ hold since $f(0)=2=3\cdot0^2-0+2$ and $f(1)=4=3\cdot 1^2-1+2$.

Now, suppose inductively that $f(k)=3k^2-k+2$ for $k\leq n$. Then 
$$
f(n+1)
= 2f(n)-f(n-1)+6
$$
You can now apply the induction hypothesis to obtain the result.

Comment: Don't you also need to verify the case $n=1$?

Comment: Yeah I guess so.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I don't understand what I would apply the induction hypothesis to

Comment: We can use the induction hypothesis to write formulas for $f(n)$ and $f(n-1)$.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick what exactly would the induction hypothesis be?

Comment: The statement after "suppose inductively that".

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick whats the induction step?

Comment: induction step = inductive hypothesis