# $ (3+\sqrt{5})^n+(3-\sqrt{5})^n\equiv\; 0 \; [2^n] $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proof that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ : 
$$
(3+\sqrt{5})^n+(3-\sqrt{5})^n\equiv\; 0 \; [2^n]
$$

Comment: Have you tried writing out the binomial expansion? There are clearly going o be a lot of cancellations

Comment: The binomial is good to show that the quantity is an integer, but not for factors. Recursion plus induction is the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

If $a_n=(3+\sqrt5)^n+(3-\sqrt5)^n$

$$a_{n+2}-6a_{n+1}+4a_n=0$$

Now  use [Strong](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517440/whats-the-difference-between-simple-induction-and-strong-induction) induction like $2^m\mid a_m$ for $1\le m\le n$

Comment: Nice and simple!

Comment: As usual you are very fast ! Nice (+1) :-)

Comment: Very well done!

Comment: nice answer !!!

Answer (score 4):

Consider the recurrence relation $$a_n=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$$ with initial conditions $a_0=2$ and $a_1=3$. Use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) to find that $$a_n=\left(\dfrac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n +\left(\dfrac{3-\sqrt 5}{2} \right)^n.$$

Comment: Effectively the same as lab bhattacharjee's answer, but doing it this way makes the induction much easier, in fact, trivial.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Another view on this:

$\left(\dfrac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n +\left(\dfrac{3-\sqrt 5}{2} \right)^n$

Is the trace of the $n$-th power of

$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$

And another:

$\dfrac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}$ and $\dfrac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}$ are algebraic integers (they're roots of $x^2 - 3x + 1$). Then since $\left(\dfrac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n +\left(\dfrac{3-\sqrt 5}{2} \right)^n$ is rational, it's an integer.

All of these methods are closely related.

Comment: all the methods are identical ! It only differs at the point of how the recurssion is established ! .. using $\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1} = (\alpha+\beta)(\alpha^{n}+\beta^{n}) - \alpha\beta(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1})$ is another one for example !