# Congruence with binomial

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, congruences

I tried to prove this by induction on $k$. But I did not manage
Let $p$ be a prime. For every $k\in\{0,\cdots,p-1\}$, one has

$$\binom{p-1}k\equiv(-1)^k\pmod p.$$
By Wilson theorem, it suffices to prove that

> $$(p-1-k)!k!\equiv(-1)^{k-1}\pmod p.$$

So I tried to prove that by induction on $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pascal's identity and Wilson's theorem:

$${n-1\choose k}+{n-1\choose k-1}={n\choose k}$$

Since ${p\choose k}\equiv 0\mod p$ when $1\le k\le p-1$, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

use [Pascal's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule) and [Strong induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517440/whats-the-difference-between-simple-induction-and-strong-induction)