# Show that $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number with strong mathematical induction

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

Use strong induction to show the following :

$$\sqrt2\:\text{is an irrational number}$$ $\\$

$\color{red}{\text{Note}}$ : **P**$(n)\equiv$ $\sqrt{2}$ $\neq \large\frac{n}{b}\small\text{,}\:$$\forall b\in\mathbb{N}$.

I would like to know how to start this proof

Thanks!

Comment: What is strong induction? Is there a weak induction too?

Comment: @YourAdHere http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517440/whats-the-difference-between-simple-induction-and-strong-induction

Comment: why use strong induction here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is a mild variant of the usual proof, given in the strong induction language that is specified in the question. We show by induction that for any $n\ge 1$, there is no integer $b$ such that $\sqrt{2}= \frac{n}{b}$.

The result is true for $n=1$, since $\sqrt{2}$ is not the reciprocal of an integer. Suppose the result holds for all $k\lt n$. We show the result is true for $n$.

Suppose to the contrary that there is an integer $b$ such that $\sqrt{2}=\frac{n}{b}$. Then $n^2=2b^2$, so $n$ is even, say $n=2n'$. Then quickly we find that $b^2=2(n')^2$, so $b$ is even, say $b=2b'$. It follows that $\sqrt{2}=\frac{n'
}{b'}$.

This contradicts the induction assumption that $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be expressed as a ratio of integers, with numerator positive and less than $n$.