# Given the recurrence $T_n = 2T_{n-1} - T_{n-2}$, prove by Induction that $T_n = n$

Tags: combinatorics, induction, recurrence-relations

Given the recurrence$$T_n = 2T_{n-1}-T_{n-2},$$$$T_0=0$$$$T_1=1$$Prove by induction, that $T_n = n$.

I have the first few steps worked out.

1. Basis: $n = 1$$$T_1=1=n=1$$
2. Assume true for $n = k+1$$$T_{k+1}=2T_k-T_{k-1}$$
3. We know that $T_k=k$$$T_{k+1}=2(k)-T_{k-1}$$

But where do I go from here? I don't have the value for $T_{k-1}$, so how to I continue?

Comment: $T_{k-1} = k-1$ by the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Technically there are two types of induction: simple induction (where you only use the $T_k$ statement to prove the $T_{k+1}$ statement) and strong induction where you assume the statement to be true for $1,2,3,\ldots,k$ to prove it true for $k+1$. For more see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517440/whats-the-difference-between-simple-induction-and-strong-induction)

Comment: Isn't this what I'm trying to prove? I thought I can't use things that I'm trying to prove

Comment: @Winther, yes I am using strong induction here.

Comment: You are not assuming anything about $T_{k+1}$. You know (the strong induction hypotesis) that $T_n = n$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots,k$ so in particular it holds for $T_{k-1}$ and $T_k$

Comment: It is very easy $T_{n+1}=2T_n-T_{n-1}=2n-(n-1)=n+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $T_n = 2T_{n-1}-T_{n-2}$ is equivalent to $T_n -T_{n-1} = T_{n-1}-T_{n-2}$.

Thus $T_n -T_{n-1}$ is constant and equal to $T_1 -T_{0}=1$.

Therefore, $T_n=T_{n-1}+1$ and induction is very easy now.

Answer (score 2):

We have$ T_0 = 0 , T_1 = 1 . $I will prove inductively that$ T_n = n .(1)$

Let $(1) $be true at $n= k .$
Thus ,$ T_{k+1} =2T_k-T_{k-1} = 2k-(k-1) = k+1$ . So $(1)$ is also true at $n = k .$

I have completed the proof :$T_n = n$

Comment: slight mistake. should be: let (1) be true for n=k-1,k. then (1) is true for n=k+1.