# Why do we switch variables in strong induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm in an introduction to proofs class and during our discussion of strong induction the professor kept telling us to switch our variables. Why is this? Why, when proving a statement P(n), would it make sense to prove P(k) $\forall k \in\mathbb{N}$, such that k < n, and then show that P(k) $\implies$ P(n+1), instead of just showing P(n) for n < n+1?

Comment: You may find some relevant information on [What's the difference between simple induction and strong induction?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517440/whats-the-difference-between-simple-induction-and-strong-induction)

Answer (score 0):

Your account of what the professor said seems to be a bit garbled. But that may be the topic of a different question: what is *proved* vs. what is *assumed* in each part of an inductive proof, and how to make your use of $<$ vs. $\leq$ and $n$ vs. $n+1$ consistent.

The whole point of using a notation like $P(n)$ is that you can put different things inside the parentheses: $P(1),$ $P(2),$ $P(n+1),$ or $P(k).$ Now in strong induction we want to prove the inductive step for an arbitrary number $n,$ and we say something about every number less than $n.$ So what name shall we use to represent "every number less than $n$"? We can't re-use the name $n$ for this variable: that would say $n < n,$ a contradiction.