# Alternative methods to avoid induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction, alternative-proof

It's well known that if you want to prove a theorem that involves $n$ elements (terms,sets,variables,sequences,etc.) you should think about induction.

But is there another way to proof a theorem with that characteristics?

For instance:

What if I prove that the result holds for the base case $(n=1)$ and then for $n=2$ and $n=3.$ Could I conclude that the result holds for the $n$ case$?$

Comment: You really need to clarify your question, because as it stands, I could give a statement like "all natural numbers are less than 4".  It works for 1,2,3, but obviously not for all n.

Comment: In induction, you show that a statement $P(k)$ holds for $k=1$ (or some other base case), and then show that $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$. There is a variant called [strong induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517440/whats-the-difference-between-simple-induction-and-strong-induction), in which you show $P(1)$, then show that for any $k$, $$\left[ \, P(1) \text{ and } P(2) \text { and } P(3) \text{ and } \cdots \text{ and } P(k)\, \right] \,\,\implies\,\, P(k+1)$$

Comment: @Ted haha I really like you counterexample..

Comment: I personally choose to believe that there are no integers greater than 3 (because I'm really bad at counting). For me, what you wrote definitely works.

Comment: :D hahaha! yea I'm starting to think that it's one of my best ideas that I've ever had @ClementC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is you can't guarantee it'll hold for the $n$ case. One example for instance are the [Borwein integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral), who follow a pattern up to $n=14$ then fail at the next iteration. This is the worry with many conjectures out there like the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Experimental_evidence) that's been checked for $ 5×2^{60}$ iterations, but could *technically* fail at one point, until we prove it always holds (induction doesn't necessarily work for Collatz, but you get my drift.)

Induction doesn't "right off the bat" *prove* it works for all integers, you just show it works for a base case and induction guarantees it'll hold for the next integer -- and as a result, the one after, and one after, etc.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/111461/111946) and have a look at the related answers in that thread. All are very interesting :)

Answer (score 4):

Nope.
You have only proved it for
$n=1,2,3$.

In general,
you can only prove that kind of theorem
by induction.

If you seem to avoid induction,
you will have to use theorems
that themselves are proved 
by induction.

For example,
consider this proof that,
if 
$s(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n k
$
then
$s(n)
=\frac12 n(n+1)
$.

Changing the order of summation,
$s(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n (n+1-k)
$.
Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
 2s(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n k+\sum_{k=1}^n (n+1-k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (k+n+1-k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (n+1)\\
&=n(n+1)
\end{array}
$

Look - no induction!

However,
the definition of
$\sum_{k=1}^n$
and the manipulation
of the summation indices
both depend on induction
to prove that
they can be used as stated.

Another way to see this is
to note that the
Peano axioms
which define the integers
only have one way
to do the definition:
induction.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. I think it may be worth noting that you can avoid ever explicitly referencing induction if you assume an equivalent axiom, such as [well-ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Equivalence_with_the_well-ordering_principle)